# systemverilog assertion become vacuous match when it has if...else statement

Tags: system-verilog

I met an vacuous match issue. When the if condition is false, code will go to else statement. But I don't know why it is vacuous match. Code as below:

```
property wr_cmd_will_set_busy ;

    @(negedge pclkdbg) disable iff(rst_a  )
    ( apb_new_trans  && (paddr_dm == ADDR_ABS_COMM) && (pwrite_dm) ) |-> 
    if(pwdata_dm[17])
        ##[0:1] $rose(abs_stat_busy)
    else
        $stable(abs_stat_busy)[*3] ; 

endproperty
```

the waveform is here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPra8.png)
I am doubting that if I cannot use if...else statement here. Thanks

Comment: This could be a tool visualization issue. But you are using a nesting implication. See https://verificationacademy.com/forums/t/nested-implication/30950/3

Comment: oh!! it's you. Hi dave. I've seen you answered a lot of people's questions. I never thought I'd get an answer from you. So excited. But can you where the nesting implication i used. There is only one '|->' here. Thanks again!

Comment: if/else is another form of  implication

Comment: okay. Does this cause the vacuous match?  I just don't want to maintain two properties, so I use if/else statement.

Comment: You need to provide a [minimal, complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Otherwise it takes too much time to analyze.

Comment: Hi Dave. Thanks for your suggestion. I will try to provide a minimal,complete reproducible example.